# Do USB interrupt transfers guarantee order?

Tags: usb, communication

I've found in the fairly awesome book titled ["USB in a NutShell"](http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Interrupt) that interrupt transfers provide reliable delivery (via error detection and automatic retry).

But I wonder, does that guarantee that transfers will not be swapped in order someday? As far as the bus is *serial*, my guess is that yes, reordering should never occur. But I'm not really much into this, so having doubts.

Could somebody clarify?

Comment: I certainly can't imagine a situation where the transfers could come out of order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interrupt packets are guaranteed to be delivered in order.  In fact, ALL USB packets defined through USB 2.0 (bulk, isochr, interrupt, control, including split-transaction / etc) are delivered in-order.

There's no sequence numbering in the wire packets (beyond DATA0/DATA1 which is used to disambiguate lost packets), so each packet is retried on the wire until delivered successfully.

I haven't worked on USB 3.0 so it's possible something new has been created that's not in-order, but even if so, the existing ones will continue to remain in-order.